# Why is my external CSS link 404 upon load?

Tags: css, sinatra, erb

I tried almost every combination of relative and absolute paths to the CSS file using JavaScript successfully however Sinatra and ERB are more unique.

In the Sinatra script I have the public and stylesheet directories as conventionally done. In my views directory I have the view page with the external

```
<link href='/some_dir/some_css_file.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I attempted this many times and perhaps it's some nuanced thing I am missing.

How can I get my ERB view file to load the external CSS link?

Sinatra does not have URL helper methods like Rails. I tried moving the CSS file adjacent to the view file and different combinations of relative and absolute paths to the file, but none of them  worked.

This code will show a 404 in the Shotgun server log:

ERB view:

```
<html>
  <head> 
  <link href='../public/stylesheets/sent' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sent.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
```

CSS file:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 18px;
}
h1 { 
    color: green;

}    
p { 
    color: orange;
}
```

In the terminal while running Shotgun I get These types of errors:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2019:23:24:47 -0800] "GET /sent.css HTTP/1.1" 404 509 0.0543
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2019:23:24:47 -0800] "GET /public/stylesheets/sent HTTP/1.1" 404 534 0.0617
```

Answer (score 0):

`body` is not closed in your CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 18px;
    }
h1 { 
    color: green;

   } 

p  { 
    color: orange;
  }
```

Comment: While this was an issue it wasn't going to cause the problem the OP asked about, and should probably have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

For future users of Sinatra making custom MVC apps:

I fixed this problem by storing the `public` folder in the root dir. This is a convention in Sinatra MVC to keep CSS/JavaScript/pictures in the `public` directory at the root of the program.

I had it incorrectly nestled in the application directory. Once I moved it up and into the root directory, my relative path `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/sent.css" />`  worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sinatra, by default, looks for CSS files in a directory called Public, you don't have to include the folder name "Public" on your link tag.

You can still use subfolders inside of the Public folder.

This should work in this case:

```
  <link href='/stylesheets/sent/sent.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

If you still want to change the location of the Public folder you can do it by changing  the Sinatra configuration, look for this `set :public_folder, Proc.new { File.join(root, "static") }`
 on the following link:
http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html